# Is there any occasion in which <style> is preferred instead of a css file?

Tags: html, css

It seems that there is no need for using the style element, when you can just write on the css file.

Is there any occasion in which it's better to use 'style' over the css file?

Comment: The css files are used to write css rules that are supposed to be used in multiple page. Its a good to way to keep html and css separate. But sometimes if you need to make slightly custom css just for one page, it might be a good idea to write that in the page.

Comment: One instance where you could do this is when you create the styles in JavaScript. Appending a `<style>` element to the head is much less cumbersome than creating a .css file, writing to it and then loading it back in.

Answer (score 1):

`<Style>` tag is preferred when you use it inside a web page that has a unique style that no other pages use. Otherwise, you use a css to declare styles used by several pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple elements which adopt the same style, it's better to use `<style>` rather than for example `<p style = ....>`, furthermore you can also have external style sheets if the same style is used for multiple pages